# SQL Subquery help for a noob

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I work in recruiting and would like to get a list of jobs that are posted to multiple offices along with the names of those offices per job.

I started with the query below to identify the jobs with multiple offices.  What is my next step for showing offices.name for only jobs with multiple offices?  Bonus if I can get one record per job and have the office names fill into columns.  I'm using SQL Workbench connected to Amazon Redshift.  Thanks much!

```
select jobs_offices.job_id, count(offices.id)
from jobs_offices join offices on jobs_offices.office_id = offices.id
group by jobs_offices.job_id
having count(offices.id) >1
order by count(offices.id) DESC
```

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to determine if there are any jobs posted in EMEA, AMER and/or APAC at the same time.  I'm creating a Tableau dashboard and need to group jobs by office (EMEA, AMER and/or APAC) and am hoping to just bring office data into Tableau using max(office) to avoid multiple records.  If that makes any sense!

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks good so far, it is just missing the office name? I believe you could get a comma-separated list of the offices by adding the [listagg](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/listagg-group-concat-and-string-agg) function. Something like `select jobs_offices.job_id, listagg(offices.name, ', ') from ...`

[Redshift docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Adding offices.name gets me only those jobs where the same office is listed more than once.

Comment: and thank you for the listagg function.  i will use that for sure!

Answer (score 0):

you can use corelated subquery

```
select t.* from offices t
      where exists ( select 1 from jobs_offices t1 where t1.office_id=t.id
                        group by t1.job_id
                       having count(*) >1 
                    )
```

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like amazon doesn't support this type of query yet.  [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet.      Any ideas on how to get around the amazon limitations?